# Why is Islam called "The Religion of Peace"?

Tags: terminology

What does it mean. Is this politically correct term to describe Islam? What is its origin?

[Islam - Religion of Peace - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_of_Peace)

Answer (score 11):

À la [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_of_Peace):

> The religion of peace is a political neologism used as a description
>   of Islam. After the September 11, 2001 attacks, some politicians
>   described Islam as a "religion of peace" in an effort to differentiate
>   between Islamic terrorists, islamism, and non-violent Muslims.

While Islam itself has always contained elements that favour peace, there is no reason to believe that the exact coinage "The Religion of Peace" has an Islamic origin.  It's merely a turn of phrase that has become popular.

Comment: I do not agree with the wikipedia article in whole. I have heard the coinage 'the religion of peace' far before 9/11. I am looking for more authoritative answer here. **Is it the religion of peace or is it not? If it is why? Is it correct to call Islam, the religion of peace?**

Comment: @TheTruthSeaker "Islamic Terrorism" had been around well before 2001; the basic desire to differentiate between the terrorists and the non-violent has always been there, 9/11 just pushed it more to the fore.

Answer (score 4):

From a linguistic point of view (which is what I believe you seek), Islam is derived from the Arabic word `سلام` (pronounced `salaam`) which literally means: peace. The common greeting in Islam is `السلام عليكم` (pronounced `alsalaam alaikum`), which translates to: peace be upon you.

To get a better understanding of *why* Islam is considered a religion of peace, you can read [this article](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,175987,00.html) in the Time Magazine by Karen Armstrong.

Comment: @FloatingRock Islam means 'submission' not peace. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TheTruthSeaker yes, it does mean submission. Your question however was regarding the reason why Islam is called the Religion of Peace, and I explained the connection. These words are all linked, and the origin of the word is `سلم` which is `peace`.

Comment: @FloatingRock I am not asking this from linguistic point of view really. I am looking for a solid reason, why it is called "The religion of peace".

Answer (score -1):

Islam come from SALAM wich is peace in english this a vocabulary definition 
and Islam recommends always good manners in dealing with people And not to harm peaceful people